is there damage from tires on axle being a different size?
After I had a tire blowout, I learned that the dealer had replaced 2 tires 18 months, 20,000 miles ago with 235/50 r17 tires instead of 225/50 r17 tires. My car is a 2019 Honda Accord Hybrid 4 door with 40,000 miles total. The tires had been rotated so the two oversized ones were on the left side. Is there a way to tell if the differential and other workings are damaged?

Why would the differential be damaged? Its purpose is to deal with wheels that are turning at different rates. There might be uneven wear on steering or stability components, but wear is not damage.

I doubt you did any real damage, but realistically, if you've got two tires of one size and two of another, you really need to have the same sized tires on the same axle. That way you won't have any concern about any of these issues.

Thank you for your feedback. As a non-tire person, I originally bought two tires because I was told the difference in tread depth could cause damage if I drove it for any length of time. It did not make sense to me that there would not be abnormal wear, damage from a larger tire. I looked at the calculator mentioned in another post https://www.inchcalculator.com/tire-size-calculator/ and food the 225 tires rotate 780 times per mile while the larger tires have 12 fewer rotations per mile (768). Researching further, I had the tires rotated at 28K (a difference of over 144,000 revolutions).

The car was handling poorly in rain so I am having the all season tires replaced with  four new all weather tires.
